# Scaler Transform help sklearn

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a logistic regression assignment and my professor has this code example.

What is the `new_x` variable and why are we transforming it as a matrix?

```py
data = pd.DataFrame( {’id’: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ’Label’: [’green’, ’green’, ’green’, ’green’,
’red’, ’red’, ’red’, ’red’],
’Height’: [5, 5.5, 5.33, 5.75, 6.00, 5.92, 5.58, 5.92],
’Weight’: [100, 150, 130, 150, 180, 190, 170, 165], ’Foot’: [6, 8, 7, 9, 13, 11, 12, 10]},
columns = [’id’, ’Height’, ’Weight’, ’Foot’, ’Label’] )

X = data[[’Height’, ’Weight’]].values 
scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
Y = data[’Label’].values 
log_reg_classifier = LogisticRegression()
log_reg_classifier.fit(X,Y)
new_x = scaler.transform(np.asmatrix([6, 160])) 
predicted = log_reg_classifier.predict(new_x) 
accuracy = log_reg_classifier.score(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it step by step.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame( {’id’: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ’Label’: [’green’, ’green’, ’green’, ’green’,
’red’, ’red’, ’red’, ’red’],
’Height’: [5, 5.5, 5.33, 5.75, 6.00, 5.92, 5.58, 5.92],
’Weight’: [100, 150, 130, 150, 180, 190, 170, 165], ’Foot’: [6, 8, 7, 9, 13, 11, 12, 10]},
columns = [’id’, ’Height’, ’Weight’, ’Foot’, ’Label’] )
```

You create an initial feature matrix that contains the columns `[’id’, ’Height’, ’Weight’, ’Foot’, ’Label’]`.

```py
scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
Y = data[’Label’].values
```

You than obtain a `np.array`, that contains only `weight` and `height` using `data[[’Height’, ’Weight’]].values`. See pandas docs on [slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) for more info. You can obtain the size of the feature matrix with `X.shape` i. e., `[n,2]`.

```py
X = data[[’Height’, ’Weight’]].values 
scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
Y = data[’Label’].values 
log_reg_classifier = LogisticRegression()
log_reg_classifier.fit(X,Y)
```

You use those two features only to train the logistic regression after [standardization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).
That is your classifier is learned on two features (i. e., height and weight) only, but mutliple samples. Every classifier in sklearn implements the [`fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) method to fit the classifier to the training data.

As your model is trained on a feature matrix with two features, your sample that you want to predict (`new_x`) also needs two features. Thus, you first create a `np.asmatrix([6, 160]` with shape `[1,2]` and elements `[height=6,weight=160]`, scale it and pass it to your trained model. [`log_reg_classifier.predict(new_x)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) returns the prediction. You assess the performance of the classifier by comparing the prediction with the true label and calculating the (mean) [accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html). Et voila.

```py
new_x = scaler.transform(np.asmatrix([6, 160])) 
predicted = log_reg_classifier.predict(new_x) 
accuracy = log_reg_classifier.score(X, Y)
```